# How to detect some elements in a vector?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector, say [1,2,710]. When I take exp([1,2,710]), I obtain ans=[2.7183,7.2891,Inf]. As the final answer is a very large number, I want to detect it first and reset it to a very large value, say 1e+305. I use isinf to help me, but isinf(ans) gives all 0. What should I do to solve the problem? Note that the input vector may change.

Comment: Which version are you using? For me on R2015a, R2013a and R2009, `isinf(exp([1,2,710]))` returns `[0 0 1]`. And the function [`isfinite`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfinite.html) work the same in reverse: `isfinite(exp([1,2,710]))` => `[1 1 0]`. My guess is that `ans` does not hold what you think (you probably overwrote it already). Do not use `ans`. Name your variables adequately and do your operations on them.

Comment: I use the version R2014a. Let me double check again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Btw, what is the largest number which can be displayed in matlab which does not give Inf? How do I get such number in matlab?

Comment: That would be `realmax`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 maximum_num = 99999;

vec = [1,2,710];
expVec = exp(vec);

expVec(expVec > maximum_num) = maximum_num;
```

`maximum_num` stores the largest value you allow in your vector. so if your working with double your can simply use `maximum_num= realmax` instead of the first line of code.